# How do I create timestamp url or where can I find free timestamp url for MSIX app packages

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, code-signing, msix

When I self sign my app packages, visual studio only allows me to create a security certificate that is valid for one year. How can I create a timestamp url or where can I find a free timestamp url to ensure the MSIX package can be installed, even after the used signing certificate has expired?
[image]

Update:

I tried many urls I could find online, most of them gave me the error:

SignTool Error: The specified timestamp server either could not be reached or returned an invalid response.

Finally I found one (http://timestamp.comodoca.com) that worked from this article https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/68/0/time-stamping-server

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try one of these, we checked them a few months ago and all worked:

http://timestamp.digicert.com
http://timestamp.comodoca.com
http://timestamp.globalsign.com
http://tsa.starfieldtech.com
http://timestamp.entrust.net/TSS/RFC3161sha2TS
http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp
http://tsa.swisssign.net

Comment: I tried all of them, got the same error for all of them. SignTool Error: The specified timestamp server either could not be reached or
returned an invalid response.

Comment: Updated list (these ones where tested by our team a few months ago, at least some of them should still be running.

Comment: Only http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp worked as of 30 December 2021.

Comment: K Software has a free signing tool (ksign) that automatically adds the timestamp for you.

Comment: As of 2023-09-18 some of these sites seem to be expecting POST traffic only and are not presenting a nice frontend to those visiting via a browser. Globalsign and Sectigo are in the latter category. Entrust at least gives a relatively meaningful error message: "method GET is not allowed, but [POST] are"